# What happens if I cancel/downgrade my iCloud storage plan?

Tags: icloud

I have more media that can possibly be stored on my iPhone, so I assume that most of it is stored in iCloud and downloaded when required (when I view it).

What happens if I cancel/downgrade my iCloud storage plan?

How do they decide what media is going to be deleted, so that the amount falls within the free plan?

Is there a time period where I can cancel and then sign back up and it'll be as if nothing has happened?

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to access and clean up your iCloud storage, but some services will be unavailable for you.

> If you downgrade your storage plan and your content exceeds the
>   storage you have available, new photos and videos won't upload to
>   iCloud Photo Library and your devices stop backing up to iCloud.
>   iCloud Drive and the other apps that you use with iCloud won’t update
>   across your devices. You can't send or receive messages with your
>   iCloud email address. Learn how to manage your storage by deleting
>   backups, documents, photos, and email messages that you don't need
>   anymore. If you cancel your plan or you don't renew it, you'll
>   automatically go back to 5GB of free storage.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201318

Comment: Hi. So does data ever forcibly get deleted? It's just that I won't be able to add any more to it?

Comment: @user6888062 If I understand it correctly, data will not be removed. But this policy may be changed by Apple any moment in future.

Comment: And I didn't test this behavior at all, just found a link to an official resource.